# Codeigniter - Transaction Test Mode Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, transactions

So what am I doing wrong? When I run the following code, the database is always updated even though transactions is in test mode.

```
/**
 * update_batch
 * This updates multiple rows. The data array must include the game_id and game_type_prize_id
 * @param array
 * @return bool
 * @author zechdc
 */
function update_batch($data)
{
    $result = TRUE;

    foreach($data as $prize)
    {
        $this->db->trans_start(TRUE); //first param is set to TRUE for test mode.
        $this->db->where('game_id', $prize['game_id']);
        $this->db->where('game_type_prize_id', $prize['game_type_prize_id']);
        $this->db->update('game_prizes', $prize);
        $this->db->trans_complete();

        if($this->db->affected_rows() == -1)
        {
            $result = FALSE;
        }
    }


    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AbhishekDilliwal provided us with the answer in his comments. If he posts the answer I will delete mine and accept his so he gets credit instead of me.

---

### Answer:

Codeigniter Transactions Test Mode Currently Does Not Work.

---

### Solution:

Replace:

```
$this->_trans_failure = ($test_mode === TRUE) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

with:

```
$this->_trans_status = ($test_mode === TRUE) ? FALSE : $this->_trans_status;
```

in the following codeigniter system files:

```
system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php
system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
system/database/drivers/oci8/oci8_driver.php
system/database/drivers/odbc/odbc_driver.php
system/database/drivers/postgre/postgre_driver.php
system/database/drivers/sqlite/sqlite_driver.php
```

It looks like [rommelxcastro](https://github.com/rommelxcastro) submitted [the fix](https://github.com/rommelxcastro/CodeIgniter/commit/6f4ffeb35fdc06024c63de0fc929566140b8176a) to the github repo already. Now we just have to wait for Codeigniter to pull it and release a new version :)

---

### Sources:

- Abhishek Dilliwal's comment
- https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/5
- https://github.com/rommelxcastro/CodeIgniter/commit/6f4ffeb35fdc06024c63de0fc929566140b8176a

Comment: Using `$this->_trans_status = ($test_mode === TRUE) ? FALSE : $this->_trans_status;` means that if you set `$test_mode` to TRUE, the transaction always fails, meaning it rollbacks, which is true for test_mode, but makes it useless for debugging. If `$test_mode` is TRUE, I'd still want my transaction to "appear" to have worked, if it was indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing your queries in plain SQL, rather than using the library functions like where() and update()? I'm not sure on this, but the CI docs only show the query() function in the docs.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

Comment: yeah its a known issue see the quick solution here
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/5

Comment: @AbhishekDilliwal Please post your comment as an answer. I went ahead and posted it as an answer, but I would like to give you credit for finding the answer. So please post an answer and I will delete mine. Thanks for your help!